# How to write a simple debugger?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, debugging

I would like to connect my compiled object code to the c++ code, and then to check if a certain line of code was executed.
How to do those two things?

If the explanation is not simple (I bet it is not), can someone at least point to some web pages explaining how to do this?

I understand that the solution is different for different platforms, but I am interested in how it is done on windows and linux (linux for the start)

Comment: Why not just use existing debuggers?

Comment: @Erik I know the debuggers are very complex, and I am not interested in creating one. I would just like to gather informations on how to check which methods/functions are executed during the execution, and how many times.

Comment: What "compiled object code" is this? Depending on your level of control, it might be as easy as adding a printf() statement before/after the line of code you want to know about. Alternately, you may want to look into how to override functions on your platform of choice (sometimes referred to as swizzling). On many platforms, you can replace a function's entry in a linker table with your own function, do your printf, then have that call the original. At worst you could also replace a function's first machine instruction with a jump instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know how it is done,

- gdb is open source
- the [`ptrace` syscall](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) should get you started,
- [libunwind-ptrace](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/man/libunwind-ptrace%283%29.html)

[this is a nice article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6100?page=0,3) using ptrace

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you don't really need a debugger but a profiler. I like the callgrind at http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html, which has a nice graphical environment at http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/.

To try I'd use

```
$ valgrind --tool=callgrind ./myapp
$ kcachegrind callgrind.out.xxx
```

Comment: That's not really what I was looking for, but valgrind is open source. So, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you say "I would just like to gather informations on how to check which methods/functions are executed during the execution, and how many times".

If that is what you want to achieve, then use a profiler such as gprof.

Compile your program with -g -pg and when your program finishes it will create a file which can be processed by gprof to show you what you want.

Comment: Right, but I want to do it from my application - without a need to compile the library or a program with additional options (-pg for gcc).